# Create wordlist without rearranging characters in the charset

Tags: dictionary, passwords, brute-force

I am attempting to create a word list from the word 'welsh'

Currently using this python script:

```
import itertools
res = itertools.permutations('wWeElLsShH', 5)
for i in res:
print ''.join(i)
```

This is successful in printing out a possible word list but is there anyway to alter this code so that the characters are not rearranged. Leading to only different combinations of capital and lowercase versions of the word being printed.

So at the moment I am getting:

wWeEl
wWeEL
wWeEs

etc...

But I am hoping for

Welsh
WElsh 
WELsh
WELSh
WELSH
wElsh

etc...

I have also used crunch but again this prints out more characters that necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import *
for funcs in product((str.lower, str.upper), repeat=5):
    print ''.join(func(letter) for func, letter in zip(funcs, 'welsh'))
```

Output:

```
welsh
welsH
welSh
welSH
weLsh
weLsH
weLSh
weLSH
wElsh
wElsH
wElSh
wElSH
wELsh
wELsH
wELSh
wELSH
Welsh
WelsH
WelSh
WelSH
WeLsh
WeLsH
WeLSh
WeLSH
WElsh
WElsH
WElSh
WElSH
WELsh
WELsH
WELSh
WELSH
```